# Check decimal? for null

Tags: c#

I want to return "NA" string if the decimal value is null or 0.  I've tried the following command, but it doesn't work:

```
var value = (tmpValue == null) ? (decimal?)tmpValue : "NA";
```

I've already initialized `tmpValue` as:

```
decimal? tmpValue = 0;
```

Basically, if `tmpValue` is 0 or null, I want to return "NA".  Note:  I don't want to convert `tmpValue` to string, as formulas as based on the decimal value.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to assign to `value` if `tmpValue` is a nonnull nonzero decimal?  Right now you are attempting to assign two different types to `value`; a `decimal?` or a `string` depending on what `tmpValue == null` evaluates to .

Comment: I want either the decimal value if there is a value or "NA" if it is 0 or null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var value = (tmpValue ?? 0) != 0 ? tmpValue : (dynamic)"NA";
```

Comment: Short & sweet!  Thx for this.

Comment: If you try to use the value as a decimal, after its been cast to a dynamic type and has the value "NA", you'll get a runtime exception. This code, while short and sweet, is doomed to cause bugs unless you use it properly by doing runtime type checking after it runs. I'm glad you got your solution though!

Answer (score 2):

```
public string IsDecimalNull(decimal? value){
    return value == null || value == 0 ? "NA" : value.ToString();
}
```

That should do exactly what you want. Since you only care about the NA you'd use it like below. I have it return `value.ToString()` because it's better than returning an empty string though you could change it to do that.

```
if (IsDecimalNull(tmpValue) == "NA"){
    //do what you want with the null value
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this change tmpValue to a string? Is it possible for tmpValue to be dynamic & only be a string for nulls & 0s?

Comment: No it doesn't change anything. And not unless it's an object and you cast it to a string or decimal. But that's bad.

Comment: It simply checks for null or zero, and outputs NA or the string representation of the decimal. Beyond checking the return value for NA, you do not need to use the return from the function. It simply tells you if the value is null by outputting NA if it is, or the string version of it if it isn't. You do not need (or want) to use the string value if you're going to do math with the decimal.

Comment: You should know, though, that in javascript the string `"8.05"` is treated the same as the decimal value `8.05`. But that's javascript which is a weakly typed language -- c# is a strongly typed language.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the null values first, then convert to a string.

```
var value = (tmpValue ?? 0M) != 0M ? tmpValue.ToString() : "NA";
```

You can't have it both ways, you either should work with decimals or you work with strings.  Probably a better way to deal with this is to change `0M` values to `null` so when you are ready to format your numbers, you can treat all nulls as `"NA"`.

Comment: Isn't string interpolation a c# 6.0 feature? The question is tagged c#-4.0.